# Can c++ compiler optimization clear unused data structures before the scope ends?

Tags: c++, memory, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code:

```
#include <set>
template <int n>
std::set<int> utility_function(std::set<int> const & input){
    // ...
}

void f(std::set<int> && set1){
    std::set<int> set2 = utility_function<1>(set1);
    // set1.clear();
    std::set<int> set3 = utility_function<2>(set2);
    // set2.clear();
    std::set<int> set4 = utility_function<3>(set3);
    // set3.clear();

    // ... use set4, without refering to set1, set2, set3
}
```

I know it may be considered bad practice and there are better ways to write this code, but assuming this is a WIP and I'm just trying to get it to work before wasting time on refactoring:

Is it theoretically possible for the compiler to clear the unused data structures `set1`, `set2`, `set3` as suggested in the comments (or simply release the underlying memory)?

Do compilers actually do that?

Comment: Not knowing the contents of `utility_function`, it can generally not. `utility_function` could be storing and accessing pointers/references/iterators to the vectors. You might want to give a more specific example.

Comment: Considering that `utility_function` returns by value, meaning it returns a *copy* of a vector, that copy will be independent or the original vector. However, and as mentioned, we don't know what else `utility_function` is doing, or what might happen after `f` returns, and neither can really the compiler.

Comment: Also, *why* should the compiler clear the vectors? `v2`, `v3` *and* `v4` will be "cleared" as they are destructed when the function `f` ends. And no compiler will do something that isn't requested of it, it won't clear or free any dynamically allocated memory like that of a vector.

Comment: With as-if rule, it might clear before, but I doubt any compiler do that.

Comment: Also important to know is the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), *iff* the compiler can deduce that neither `v2` nor `v3` will be used again after the third call to `utility_function` then it could generate code to destruct those objects immediately, but this is quite hard to check for and will likely not happen.

Comment: walnut, Some programmer dude: I disagree. As these sets (editted to replace the vectors) are of a simple int, and are passed by value - there can be no nefarious code that the compiler cannot predict after `utility_function` returns.

Comment: Some programmer dude, Jarod42 - thanks, I did not know this 'as-if rule'. This probably answers the first question.

Comment: @BennyK You are not passing them by-value. You are passing them by-reference. If they were passed by-value to `utility_function` and there existed no other references to the containers or their elements, then the compiler *could* do this optimization (except for `set1`).

Comment: My two cents: stack unwinding at scope end and destructors are called, nothing else the compiler is allowed to do.

Comment: @walnut - good point. I accept that there might be some nefarious side-effecte if references are kept and are used indirectly in `f`... However, this isn't the intended point. Assume that `utility_function` is simply replaced with some straight-forward calculation in-place.

Comment: Why do you care if it does or doesn't clear them?

Comment: @Caleth - If said sets are large, and the heap is already mostly full, clearing unused data before the end of the scope (and before more memory is allocated in this scope) might make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the as-if rule it is theoretically possible for the compiler to remove the unused data structures if it can deduce that removing them will not change the semantics of the program. To do this the compiler must prove that `utility_function` do not keep any of the sets as part of an internal state. It must also prove that reordering construction and destruction will have no observable effects.

Whether a compiler will remove the data early depends on the functions involved, i.e. `f`, `utility_function`, and the constructors and destructors for `set`.

As an answer to a question that is only implicitly stated, I strongly advice against relying on a specific optimization for the correctness of a program. If you need to clear the sets for the dataset to fit in memory you should do this explicitly.